# Setting Up TFS In Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Can anyone please advide regarding setting up TFS 2015 Community Edition ?

1. I have gone to Tools >> Options and set values to Team Foundation Server instead of GitHub
2. Watched and followed steps from YouTube videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G3Ju69SWU4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH7QZcTEPN4

All the steps have not helped me resolve the issue.

I have a Microsoft TFS Account as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to set up TFS as my source control. I am using MS/VS 2015 Community Edition. I cannot use it to check in or check out code. So, currently I am just able to write code in V/Studio. I can't deploy it to my repository (TFS).

Comment: See my answer below, if you don't a success, write which step you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image] - You need to have permissions connect to the TFS server.
 - On the Tools menu, click Connect to Team Foundation Server.
 - In the Connect to Team Foundation Server dialog box, select a Team Foundation Server from the drop-down list.

> Note: If the drop-down list is empty, click the Servers button to
>   manually enter the Team Foundation settings. Contact your Team
>   Foundation Server administrator or team project administrator for the
>   correct Team Foundation Server connection settings.

- Under Team projects, select one or more team projects from the list. Team projects with a check mark next to them will display in Team Explorer.
- Click OK.
- Team Explorer displays the team projects under the selected Team Foundation Server.
- Connect to a specific team project.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But, I cannot launch TFS from the Tools Menu. I have attached a screen shot. Instead, I access it from the Team Explorer Tab.